# How can do UWP form make Http call in Xmarin PCL project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp-xaml

Hi I am using following code, It's always giving response that server not found but while I test the same from console form its working.

```
using (Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            Uri url = new Uri(Constant.DATABASE_LIST_API);
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
            Task< Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage> responseAsync = client.SendRequestAsync(httpRequest).AsTask();
            responseAsync.Wait();
            responseAsync.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            Task<Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer> asyncBuffer = responseAsync.Result.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync().AsTask();
            asyncBuffer.Wait();
            byte[] resultByteArray = asyncBuffer.Result.ToArray();
            string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultByteArray, 0, resultByteArray.Length);

            responseAsync.Result.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use "localhost" in your Constant.DATABASE_LIST_API?

If so, please try the IP address. If you are running your App in an Emulator it won't find the localhost, if your webservice is running on your local machine, because the Emulator is a different device.

Comment: :) Markus , It' working actually I din't see to wifi connection in device.